# Schedule whatsapp messages on twilio

Tags: node.js, nestjs, twilio, scheduled-tasks, whatsapp

I want to schedule a whatsapp message to send it the users at a specific time. Users are from worldwide.

So lets condiser, I want to send a whatsapp message on monday at 2 PM of their time, as users are from different countries, we need to consider their 2PM.

So, I can do that, is twilio have any kind of features ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [schedule messages](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-scheduled-sms-node-js-twilio) with Twilio. You'll need to specify the UTC time when the message should be delivered as Twilio won't be able to know in which time zone the user lives.

> The Message Scheduling feature currently requires that this time is more than one hour and less than 7 days ahead.

```js
// create a Twilio client
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

async function sendScheduledSms() {
  // schedule message to be sent 61 minutes after current time
  const sendWhen = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 61 * 60000);

  // send the SMS
  const messagingServiceSid = process.env.TWILIO_MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID;
  const message = await client.messages.create({
    from: messagingServiceSid,
    to: '+1xxxxxxxxxx',  // ← your phone number here
    body: 'Friendly reminder that you have an appointment with us next week.',
    scheduleType: 'fixed',
    sendAt: sendWhen.toISOString(),
  });

  console.log(message.sid);
}

sendScheduledSms();
```